# How to use state or props of a function in another function in react js

Tags: javascript, oop, reactjs

I have render function in which I can consume my `state` and `props`, when I call another method from here, I can pass these values and make them accessible to my other function. But, I want to call my method from `componentDidMount` function and consume the `state/props` that I can use up in render. When I call my function from `componentDidMount`, the `state/prop` data remains undefined.

`render`

```
render : function(){
    var customState = this.state.data;
    var customProp = this.props.otherData;
},
```

`componenDidMount`

```
componentDidMount : function(){
    this.myCustomFunction();
},
```

`myCustomFunction`

```
mycustomFunction : function(){
    var stateData = this.state.data.name; //undefined
},
```

Now, how can I pass the state data here?

Comment: `this.state.data.name; //undefined` - no code you posted defines it, therefore it is `undefined` - what's the problem?

Comment: When do you populate your component's state and props? it is probably that when `componentDidMount` executes, your `state` and `props` have not been populated yet

Comment: I can access the data in render, but I don't know how can I use that in myCustomFunction(), how to get the data in there?

Comment: Can you post the entire component?

Comment: The entire component cannot be posted, it is over 1200 lines and I'll have to filter lot sensitive data from there.

Comment: did you set initial state ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is correct.

```
mycustomFunction : function(){
    var stateData = this.state.data.name; //undefined
}
```

this.state.data.name is probably undefined because you are not setting it. 
Try debugging just `this.state.data` or console it and check if the data is present.